# Handling concurrency at group level rather than application level

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I would like to handle the concurrent issue in the API. Here is a situation where we get a request from multiple users for the same group. There can be multiple groups as well. Below solution i think should work, correct me

```
 // This will be a singleton across the API
 ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

 if (dict.ContainsKey(groupId)) {
    throw new Exception("request already accepted");
 } else {
     // Thinking this is thread lock operation or i can put lock statement
     if(dict.TryAdd(groupId, "Added") == false) {
        throw new Exception("request already accepted");
     }
     // continue the original logic
 }
```

After every 10 minutes, we will clean off the older keys in dictionary (note this operation should work normal i.e. like thread is not locked mode because it will be working on already used and old keys). Does concurrent dictionary have thread locking at key level rather than dictionary level? so that we don't block all the requests instead we only block particular requests related to the group. Any help is greatly appreciated.

One quick solution is having lock wrapper around `get` and `add` of dictionary operation but this would stop all the requests from proceeding, we want to block at group level. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A threadsafe collection guarantees that its internal data structures are valid at all times, even if accessed from multiple threads. A threadsafe collection does not, guarantee that sequential operations on the thread all work on the same "snapshot" of its internal data structure. By that definition, it doesn't lock the dictionary, it also doesn't stop your self from shooting your self in the foot. It does however has synchronisation features that may cause side affects with some calls, or a stale snapshot

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary only ensures that you cannot corrupt the container state.  That doesn't automatically make your own code safe.  And it is not, another thread might add the key right after the ContainsKey() check, before TryAdd().  Just don't use ContainsKey(), it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding stuff into a concurrent dictionary is a very fast operation. You are also not making threads wait for the first one to finish, you are throwing right away if they cannot acquire the lock.

That makes me think that probably [Double Checked Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) is not really needed for your case

So, I would simply do your inner check without the outer one:

```
if(dict.TryAdd(groupId, "Added") == false) 
{
        throw new Exception("request already accepted");
}
```

If you have waaaay too many request after the first one, then I would do what you have done, since ContainsKey [will not lock](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,93f90f07cf34d76c,references)

Another interesting topic is how you are going to clean this.

maybe you could do all this locking in an IDisposable object that can remove itself at dispose time. For example:

```
// NOTE: THIS IS JUST PSEUDOCODE

// In your controller, you can simply do this...
//
public SomeController()
{

    using (var operation = new GroupOperation(groupId)) 
    {
        // In here I am sure I am the only operation of this group
    } 

    // In here I am sure that the operation got removed from the dictionary

}


// This class hides all the complexity of the concurrent dictionary
//
public class GroupOperation : IDisposable
{
    var singletonDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>()
    int GroupId;

    public GroupOperation(int GroupID)
    {
         this.GroupId = GroupId;
         if(!singletonDictionary.TryADd(GroupID, 1))
         {
             throw new Exception("Sorry, operation in progress for your group");
         }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
       singletonDictionary.Remove(GroupId)
    }
}
```